# Is it true that evaluating a polynomial with integer coefficients at $e$, uniquely defines it?

Tags: polynomials, transcendental-numbers, algebraic-numbers

In other words, there can not be two different polynomials with integer coefficients that evaluate to the same real number when $x=e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because $e$ is not algebraic number.

See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number

Comment: Can you explain in more details, how the fact that $e$ is not a root of a nonzero polynomial equation with integer coefficients implies that two integer polynomials can not evaluate to the same number at $e$?

Comment: If $a_0e^n+a_1e^{n-1}+...+a_n=b_0e^n+b_1e^{n-1}+...+b_n$, where $a_i\neq b_i$ for some $i$ then $(a_0-b_0)e^n+(a_1-b_1)e^{n-1}+...+a_n-b_n=0$, which says that $e$ is an algebraic number, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now.

Comment: You are welcome!